# differential operator

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I've read journal "On the Comparison of Several Mean Values: An Alternative approach" (Welch, 1951). I don't understand this expression:
$$E\left(\exp\left[ \sum_t ( w_t - \omega_t ) D_t\right]\right),$$

where $$D_t^r = \left(\frac{\partial^r}{\partial z_t^r}\right)_{z=\omega} $$ and $E$ is expectation over $w_t$

Why is $D_t$ written in the last equation?

Comment: What kind of mathematical objects want $r,t,w,\omega$ denote? We can have some guesses, but please specify them a bit.

Comment: For more explanation, you can read this journal: http://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=On+the+Comparison+of+Several+Mean+Values%3A+An+Alternative+approach&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.soph.uab.edu%2FStatgenetics%2FPeople%2FMBeasley%2FCourses%2FWelch1951.pdf&ei=14m9UOrBLY6Qrge8hYDgBg&usg=AFQjCNE9v2uBUWrJl5dtliD-qJ_mpuT81A